# DataGridView RowsAdded event handler not working?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need a comboBox to become enabled when my DataGridView has 1 or more rows.

I have the following code which isn't firing. I am adding rows to the DataGridView using the `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(...)` method.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
   comboBox1.Enabled = (e.RowCount > 1); // ? true : false; Thanks Blogbeard  -- Changed back to (e.RowCount > 1) to show my error.
}
```

**Questions:**

Why isnt this working?

Is there a better way to do this? Another event handler that I should use?

**EDIT:**

Event handler subscription in `Form1.Designer.cs`:

```
this.dataGridView1.RowsAdded += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_RowsAdded);
```

Screenshot in VS 2010 to show the event handler should be registered to my DGV

[image]

Comment: Where/how do you register the method? It needs to listen to an event being fired.

Comment: FYI, `? true : false` is a no-op. You can remove that with no change in function of the code.

Comment: Also, your logic is off-by-one if you want the combobox enabled with one or more rows - it should be `(e.RowCount > 0)`. If you only added one row, maybe that's your problem.

Comment: @GrantWinney it is correctly subscribed, which is why I am confused as to why its not working.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: @GrantWinney I am not a copy/paster lol, the method is subscribed properly. Ive Editted my question above to show this.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Code is shown above, I will also now attach a screenshot to show it is also registered correctly.

Comment: @MickIlovski: please debug now and ensure a row gets added to your grid (`dataGridView1`). Should be all good.

Comment: @GrantWinney This worked! I changed to `(e.RowCount > 0)`. Thanks! Although it was confusing because I thought that using > 1 should also work.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I will mark as answer. Cheers.

Comment: @MickIlovski I'm confused now. I agree with Grant Winney's answer that you should have used `(dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)` instead of `(e.RowCount > x)`. If you're still using `e.RowCount`, why not might as well just `comboBox1.Enabled = True`, since rowsAdded certainly render your dgv with >0 rows?

Comment: @SamuelAdam Apologies, I meant Grant, I will mark as answer. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original code *(prior to your first edit)* looked like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
   comboBox1.Enabled = (e.RowCount > 1); // ? true : false;
}
```

The `e.RowCount` value reports how many rows you're currently adding, *not* how many rows happen to be in the `DataGridView` at the time of calling `Add()`.

In other words, if you call `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1)` repeatedly, then the above code will disable `comboBox1` every time, because you're not adding 2 or more rows at once.

Change your code accordingly:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
   comboBox1.Enabled = (e.RowCount > 0); // ? true : false;
}
```

Also, since trying to add anything *less* than 1 row will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, you might as well not even bother checking `e.RowCount`... it'll always be greater than 0.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
   comboBox1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that info, I never knew that e.RowCount reported how many rows are added, not the actual count of rows that are in the DGV. Also, I have changed my code to `comboBox1.Enabled = true` instead of checking for e.RowCount, which now makes more sense. Cheers.